# How do I compute these eigenvectors with repeated multiplicity?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvectors of $$A =
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
>    2 & 0 & 0 \\
>    4 & 2 & 3 \\
>    3 & 0 & -1
>   \end{array} } \right]$$

**Step 1.** Find the eigenvalues.

$$ \left| {\begin{array}{ccc}
   2-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
   4 & 2-\lambda & 3 \\
   3 & 0 & -1-\lambda
  \end{array} } \right| = (2-\lambda)^2(-1-\lambda)
$$

So the eigenvalues $\lambda = 2, -1$, with repeated multiplicity for $2$.

**Step 2.** The eigenvector for $\lambda = 2$ is

$$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
   4 & 0 & 3 \\
   3 & 0 & -3
  \end{array} } \right]
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   x_1 \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3
  \end{array} } \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

This gives the system of equations

$$\begin{align*} 4x_1 + 3x_3 &= 0 \\
                 3x_1 - 3x_3 &= 0 \end{align*}$$

Which gives $(x_1, x_2, x_2)$ as an "eigenvector." However, this seems extremely defective and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations imply $x_1=x_3$ and $x_1=-3/4x_3$ So $x_3 = 0, x_1=0$ and an eigenvector is $(0,1,0)$.

To find another generalized eigenvector for $\lambda =2$ you can set $(A-2I)^2x = 0$ and do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much ben.